# weird website appear with the domain jwico.com if without www

Tags: dns, cross-domain

I have this domain. on some internet providers if you try

www.jwico.com

it shows the current website.

and if you tried:

http://jwico.com

it shows the old website.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Go your hosting panel and create a subdomain name it as "www" and redirect it to your websites home directory like "home, public_html"

Comment: is says "You can't use 'www' as sub-domain name"

Comment: In subdomain list do you see www subdomain?

Comment: It is interesring situation. Normally there is a www shortcut on root folder of your ftp to redirect on your public_html or home directory. You have to ask your hosting provider what is wrong with your web page. May be it is about cache system. Complicated.